# How to select 3 items with item type

Tags: php, laravel

I try to select 3 items of the same type. Here's what I tried :

```
public function show(Work $work)
{
    $getSameType = Work::whereHas('type', function ($query){
        $query->where('name', 'Site web');
    })->whereNotIn('id', [$work->id])->get();   
}
```

It works, but I had to type the name manually. I would like it to be dynamic.

In my view, I access the type like this: `$work->type->name`, or for to have the slug `$work->type->slug`

So I tried to do the same thing in my query, but I variable indefinite as error.

```
public function show(Work $work)
{
    $getSameType = Work::whereHas('type', function ($query){
        $query->where('name', $work->type->slug);
    })->whereNotIn('id', [$work->id])->get();   
}
```

Can you help me?

Thank you very much!

Comment: I am not sure about this, but I believe you should do it like this, $query->where('name', $work->type->name); OR $query->where('slug', $work->type->slug);

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use `use` in order to use a variable inside a closure like:

```
public function show(Work $work)
{
    $getSameType = Work::whereHas('type', function ($query) use ($work) { 
        $query->where('name', $work->type->slug);
    })->whereNotIn('id', [$work->id])->get();   
}
```

PS: I didn't test above, but it should work

More info: http://php.net/manual/en/functions.anonymous.php